# How to modify the allowed end dates in a range with the easypick Javascript plugin?

Tags: javascript

I am using the [easepick](https://easepick.com/examples/hotel.html) Javascript plugin to generate a date range picker. It looks like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker"/>
<script>
  const DateTime = easepick.DateTime;
  const bookedDates = [
      '2023-04-02',
      ['2023-04-06', '2023-04-11'],
      '2023-04-18',
      '2023-04-19',
      '2023-04-20',
      '2023-04-25',
      '2023-04-28',
  ].map(d => {
      if (d instanceof Array) {
        const start = new DateTime(d[0], 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        const end = new DateTime(d[1], 'YYYY-MM-DD');

        return [start, end];
      }

      return new DateTime(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  });
  const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    css: [
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
      'https://easepick.com/css/demo_hotelcal.css',
    ],
    plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
    RangePlugin: {
      tooltipNumber(num) {
        return num - 1;
      },
      locale: {
        one: 'night',
        other: 'nights',
      },
    },
    LockPlugin: {
      minDate: new Date(),
      minDays: 2,
      inseparable: true,
      filter(date, picked) {
        if (picked.length === 1) {
          const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
          return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
        }

        return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
      },
    },
    autoApply: false,
    onApply(dates) {
     console.log(dates);
    }
  });
</script>
```

But it seems the user is unable to select an end date that is included in the `bookedDates` array. Since it should of course be possible to have the same checkout date as another user has chosen as checkin date, how do I modily my `filter` inside the `LockPlugin` to allow this?

Answer (score 1):

To modify the filter inside the LockPlugin to allow users to select an end date that is already booked by another user, you can update the conditional statement inside the filter() method to check if the picked date range overlaps with any of the booked dates.

Here's an updated filter() method that checks for date range overlap:

```
LockPlugin: {
  minDate: new Date(),
  minDays: 2,
  inseparable: true,
  filter(date, picked) {
    if (picked.length === 1) {
      const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
      return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
    }

    // Check for overlap with any booked date range
    for (let i = 0; i < bookedDates.length; i++) {
      const bd = bookedDates[i];
      const overlap = picked[0].isBetween(bd[0], bd[1], 'day', '[]') ||
                      picked[1].isBetween(bd[0], bd[1], 'day', '[]');
      if (overlap) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  },
},
```

This new filter() method checks for overlap between the user's picked date range and any booked date range. If there is overlap, it returns true, which will prevent the user from selecting that date range.

Note that this implementation assumes that bookedDates contains only date ranges (i.e., arrays with two DateTime objects). If bookedDates can contain single dates as well, you may need to modify the loop to handle those cases appropriately.

Comment: Hm seems I am getting an error when picked.length is not 2. But then I tried this approach, what do you think about it?:

```
filter(date, picked) {
  if (picked.length === 0) {
    return date.inArray(bookedDates, '[)');
  } else {
    const incl = date.isBefore(picked[0]) ? '[)' : '(]';
    return !picked[0].isSame(date, 'day') && date.inArray(bookedDates, incl);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well except not it seems it just moves every subsequent date range 1 day forward when the start date is selected. That is not a problem in terms of pure functionality. Because those can not be selected anyway. However cosmetically it is confusing, because more things than necessary are moving around.